# Database Values For User Return After Prolonged Amount Of Time?

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

**Database Values For User Return After Prolonged Amount Of Time?**

So I have values in my database e.g. stamina, max_stamina, ...

What I want to do is this:

```
If stamina is < max_stamina then
    after 60 seconds stamina=stamina+1
else
    nothing
```

I will need to loop this untill `stamina` equals `max_stamina`

I can easily create up the if statement, the problem I need help with is coding the 60 seconds, how could i go about it?

All so this will need to run when the player is and isnt logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at mysql events and schedules think that is what you are looking for. Also if you are having more than 1 users it would be smart to update them all in that 60 seconds interval you need.

Comment: Thanks this will be what im looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your code architecture, you most likely will need a cronjob to run every minute and to update all stamina records according to your criteria.

Comment: i was hoping ud say it can be coded into phpmyadmin somehow ;)